# What happens to an (AR)MA model when doing out-of-sample forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, model

What happens to the error terms in an (AR)MA model when doing out-of-sample forecasting? As I understand it, when doing an in-sample fit, the estimate is simply the residual of the ground truth data. However, in an out-of-sample setting I don't know the residual. What happens? Do I take zero as the expected value as an estimate (which would make a MA model produce constant forecasts if I understand correctly)?

Could somebody please confirm or correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking about the innovations of an MA model, I believe they are zero, and thus an MA($n$) model's prediction will be constant after $n$ steps. At least that's the way that R's `arima` prediction works, and other similar software.

It appears to me that an AR($n$) model's predictions will smooth out (not going constant, but following an unrealistic curve) between $n$ and $2n$ steps.

Seasonality will obviously enlarge $n$ by the seasonal frequency, so MA$(1)(1)_{12}$ will go flat after 12 steps. Adding in an integration allows the shape to repeat indefinitely, so an ARIMA$(0,1,1)(0,1,1)_{12}$ will repeat its shape on a sloping trend forever.

I'm sure others can answer with a nice mathematical proof, but this is all I have.